# Enable rpmbuild automatic detection of dependencies for python

Tags: python, perl, rpm, rpmbuild

The dependencies of an RPM are specified in its .spec file on the "Requires:" lines, but rpmbuild is able to detect automatically dependencies for Perl files with CentOS. I guess that such detection is supported by `/usr/lib/rpm/find-requires` which uses `/usr/lib/rpm/perl.req`.

I would like to detect automatically dependencies also for python files, but, although `/usr/lib/rpm/find-requires` seems to implement the logic similar to the Perl case, `/usr/lib/rpm/python.req` does not exist. Is something else needed?

Any other methods to enable the automatic detection of dependencies for python while building a RPM?

Answer (score 1):

This works since Fedora 25. See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Python#Automatic_Provides_with_a_standardized_name

Answer (score 1):

For a CentOS-7 box, python dependencies are generated by this script:

```
/usr/lib/rpm/pythondeps.sh
```

which is used in `/usr/lib/rpm/fileattrs/python.attr` like this,

```
 %__python_provides /usr/lib/rpm/pythondeps.sh --provides
 %__python_requires /usr/lib/rpm/pythondeps.sh --requires
```

You can do it automatically by calling the above two predefined vars in your `spec` file

Comment: The scripts do not parse the Python files to find the standardized name (i.e. dist name, name on PyPI) of the packaged software (i.e., Perl scripts seem to work via parsing). How are they supposed to work?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but calling `%__python_requires` in your build spec file should sort out dependencies.

Comment: I tired to call the aforementioned commands but  dependencies are not added to the RPM.